# React Changing the state in one child component and passing it to another child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app similar to google fonts page. I am using google fonts API, and it works fine and displays all the fonts correctly. However, there are two things that I cannot figure out. I have a menu where there is an text input field and a dropdown font size menu, and there is a main section with a card for each google font containing the name of the font and a text that shows how the font looks. There is a default text in the text input field and the default font size is 40px. The user has an option to type a text in the input field and to change the default text, and also to change the font size. Both of these require the SearchMenu component to change the values in the parent component, and the new value to be passed to the CardList component, and from there to the Card component. However, the way I have passed textfield and size doesn't work, and even the initial values that I have set for them in the constructor are not working . Here is my code:

**app.js**

```
import MainMenu from '../components/MainMenu.js';
import SearchMenu from '../components/SearchMenu.js';
import CardList from '../components/CardList.js';
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      fonts: [],
      searchfield: '',
      textfield: 'Text1',
      size: '40'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyA5GrPS2LztYbvuq-S38sx6CieY17p9FOY')
    .then(response=> response.json())
    .then(data=> this.setState({fonts: data.items}));

  }


  onSearchChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({searchfield: event.target.value })
  }

  onTextChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({textfield: event.target.value })
  }

  onSearchReset = () => {
    this.setState({searchfield: '' })
  }

  onFontSizeChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({size: event.target.value })
  }

  render () {
    const {fonts, searchfield, textfield, size} = this.state;
    const filteredFonts = fonts.filter(font => {
      return font.family.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase());
      })

    return (
      <div className='tc'>
        <MainMenu />
        <SearchMenu searchChange={this.onSearchChange} textChange={this.onTextChange} sizeChange={this.onFontSizeChange}/>
        <CardList fonts={filteredFonts} textfield={textfield} size={size}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default App;
```

**searchMenu.js**

```
const SearchMenu = ({searchfield, searchChange, textfield, textChange, sizeChange, size}) => {
    return (
        <div className='center fixed bg-white w-100 dib mt5 pb5'>         
      <nav className="ma1 dib ba br-pill tc mw-90 center">        
        <input className="f6 black-80 bw0 dib ma2 .w5" 
          type='search' 
          placeholder='Search fonts'
          onChange={searchChange} />
        <input className="f6 black-80 b--silver dib ma2 .w5" 
          type='text' 
          placeholder='Type something'
          onChange={textChange} />
        <select id="Size" 
          className='pl2 pr2 bl mr3'
          onChange={sizeChange}>
            <option value="20">20px</option>
            <option value="24" >24px</option>
            <option value="32">32px</option>
            <option value="40" selected="selected">40px</option>
          </select>

      </nav>

        </div>
    );
}

export default SearchMenu;
```

**CardList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card.js';

const CardList = ({fonts, textfield, size}) => {
    return (
        <div className='pv4 dib'> {
            fonts.map((user, i) => {
                return (<Card key={i} family={fonts[i].family}/>)
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default CardList;
```

**Card.js**

```
import React from 'react';
{/*import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";*/}
var WebFont = require('webfontloader');


const Card = ({family, textfield, size}) => {
    WebFont.load({
    google: {
      families: [`${family}`]
    }
  });

    const cardStyle = {
        fontFamily: family,
        fontSize: size
    };

    return (
        <div className='tl dib w-20 bt ma2 pa3'>
            <div>
                <h2 className='f6'>{family}</h2>
                <br />
                <p style={cardStyle}>{textfield}</p>
            </div>
        </div>      
    );
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see with the SearchMenu component is - the input field is not using the textfield value that is being passed to it as prop. Also, the app.js is not passing the textfield value to the SearchMenu component.

SearchMenu component should have something like this -

```
<input className="f6 black-80 b--silver dib ma2 .w5" 
      type='text' 
      placeholder='Type something'
      onChange={textChange} 
      value={textfield}/>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. The SearchMenu should only change the value. What is does it to change the state of the textField when onChange is triggered. So, one the user types something in the empty input field, the text in the card component should change too.

Answer (score 0):

You can send method references to the child component in the props that can change the parent state and send that state variable to the other child(say sibling component(s)) in props.

Following snippet shows how to share data between sibling components. Full demo can be found [here](https://codepen.io/mostafiz93/pen/bGNrKNd).

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count1: 0,
      count2: 0,
    }
  }

  receiveDataFromChild(child,count){ 
      this.setState({[child]: count})
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is Parent. It's child1 is clicked {this.state.count1} times and child2 is clicked {this.state.count2} times</h1>

        <Child1 
            sendDataToParent={this.receiveDataFromChild.bind(this)} 
            count={this.state.count1} 
            brotherCount={this.state.count2}/>

        <Child2 
            sendDataToParent={this.receiveDataFromChild.bind(this)} 
            count={this.state.count2}
            brotherCount={this.state.count1}/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child1 extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <h2 onClick={()=>{this.props.sendDataToParent('count1', this.props.count+1)}}> This is Chiild1. My brother  is clicked {this.props.brotherCount} times </h2>
    )
  }
}

class Child2 extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <h2 onClick={()=>{this.props.sendDataToParent('count2', this.props.count+1)}}> This is Chiild2. My brother  is clicked {this.props.brotherCount} times </h2>
    )
  }
}
```